# Function pointer compatibility between single pointer and empty parameter lists

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99, c23

I've been reading about function pointer compatibility, but have not found the following scenario documented as being acceptable (below).

With this code, it is allowed (without warnings) to call a function pointer with a parameter, even-though it is defined as having an empty parameter list. Also, a function with a single pointer as a parameter list is allowed (without warnings) to be assigned to the function pointer with type defined as having an empty parameter list. And the subsequent call with a parameter is allowed.

Since the caller is responsible for cleaning up the parameters on the stack, I suppose this is memory-safe, no? There's just something about this that makes me doubt its validity.

Does the code below compile and run without warnings because it is actually valid C? Are these function types indeed compatible, and if so, is this defined behavior?

Program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void functionA()
{
    printf("A\n");
}

void functionB(uint8_t* parameter)
{
    printf("B %d\n", *parameter);
}

void (*functionPointer)();

int main()
{
    uint8_t number = 42;

    functionPointer = functionA;
    functionPointer(&number);

    functionPointer = functionB;
    functionPointer(&number);
    
    //functionA(&number); // warning: too many arguments in call

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
% ./a.out
A
B 42
```

Comment: The semantics of empty parentheses have changed between C99 and C23. In C23 it means no arguments (i.e. `void fun()` is the same as `void fun(void)`). Before that it meant that the arguments were unspecified, and there could be any number and any type of arguments.

Comment: Interesting, so it can it be said that this code strictly conforms to the C standards before C23?


I've edited the program above to have a comment for a call to `functionA(&number);` which results in "Warning: too many arguments in call to 'functionA'". So it seems only valid via a function pointer in this scenario?

Comment: Prior to C23, the call `functionPointer(&number);` when `functionPointer` is pointing to `functionA` is UB because `functionPointer` does not include a prototype and the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters of `functionA`, but the call `functionA(&number);` is a constraint violation. In C23, both `functionA(&number);` and `functionPointer(&number);` (when `functionPointer` is pointing to `functionA`) are UB because of argument/parameter mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A declaration of a function that includes the type of its parameters is called a *prototype* (C 2018 6.2.1 2).

The rules regarding function types without parameter declarations are expected to change in C 2023. C 2023 is expected to remove non-prototype declarations from the standard and make `()` in a function declaration equivalent to `(void)`, so the code in the question will be non-conforming, making the questions asked largely moot.

The remainder of this answer addresses C 2018, which is largely unchanged in this regard from C 1999.

> I've been reading about function pointer compatibility, but have not found the following scenario documented as being acceptable (below).

Calling a function that is defined with a prototype using a expression that does not have a prototype is specified in C 2018 6.5.2.2 6. (“Expression” is used here rather than referring merely to a function name because a function can be called using a function name, a variable that is a pointer to a function type, or an expression that is a cast resulting in a pointer to a function type.) Calling a function that is not defined with a prototype using an expression that does have a prototype is specified in the following paragraphs.

> With this code, it is allowed (without warnings) to call a function pointer with a parameter, even-though it is defined as having an empty parameter list. Also, a function with a single pointer as a parameter list is allowed (without warnings) to be assigned to the function pointer with type defined as having an empty parameter list. And the subsequent call with a parameter is allowed.

Non-prototype function types essentially mean the parameters are not specified in the type. The rules about mixing uses of non-prototype function types and prototype function types are largely that, as long as the arguments used to call the function are compatible with what the function actually expects, the behavior is defined. There is some additional tolerance, such as allowing passing an `int` for an `unsigned int` provided the value is representable in both.

> Since the caller is responsible for cleaning up the parameters on the stack, I suppose this is memory-safe, no?

The C standard says nothing about how is responsible for cleaning up arguments on the stack and can be implemented on platforms that require the calling to clean up arguments and on platforms that require the called function to clean up arguments.

In any function call, the compiler knows the arguments passed from the actual arguments, regardless of whether the calling expression type has a prototype or not. So the compiler could generate code for the calling routine to clean up the arguments, if that is what the platform requires.

In a function definition with a prototype without `...`, the compiler knows the parameters from the prototype. In a function definition without a prototype, the parameters are declared in “identifier list” style: The parameter names are listed inside parentheses, and their declarations following the closing parentheses of the function parameters. So, in both of these cases, the compiler knows the parameters and hence the expected arguments and could generate code to clean up the stack if that is what the platform requires. This includes the case where a function is defined with `()`—in a function definition, this means there are no parameters and hence no arguments. (In function declaration that is not a function definition, `()` means the parameters are not specified.)

This leaves function definitions using `...`. In this case, the compiler generally cannot know the arguments. Further, the arguments are not necessarily known to the calling routine. Although `printf`, for example, has a format string that instructs it about arguments to expect, it is valid to pass `printf` more arguments than the format string calls for (C 2018 7.21.6.1 2). On a platform where the caller is responsible for cleaning up the stack, this is no problem, as the caller knows what arguments were passed. On a platform where the calling function is responsible for cleaning up the stack, this can be implemented by interface rules that require the calling routine to pass information about the arguments. This would be “hidden” information that is not visible in the arguments. For example, the interface may require the calling routine to pass the number of bytes to remove from the stack when returning from the function call.

> Does the code below compile and run without warnings because it is actually valid C?

More precisely, it may compile and execute without warnings because it is conforming C code. (“Valid” has a different meaning and is not defined in the C standard. It is valid for programs to use extensions to the C language.) However, it is not strictly conforming C code. Because the first call using `functionPointer` passes an argument to a function defined with no parameters, it violates C 2018 6.5.2.2 6: “… If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the behavior is undefined…” This makes the behavior not defined by the C standard.

Note the difference between functions defined with and without `...`. Although we can pass `printf` arguments it does not know about, the standard does not guarantee we can do that for `functionA`. The reason is that `...` puts the compiler on notice that it must, if the platform requires it, use the additional argument information discussed above. Without the `...`, the compiler may generate code expected a fixed number of arguments with fixed types, and so that would be wrong when called with a different number of arguments.

> Are these function types indeed compatible, and if so, is this defined behavior?

Yes. Rules for compatibility of function types are specified in C 2018 6.7.6.3 15, and they allow prototype types to be compatible with non-prototype types. For types in C, “compatible” largely means that two types can be completed to be the same type, *i.e.*, that any portions of them that are specified are the same. For example, an array type with a size (number of elements in the array) is compatible with an array type without a size (number is not specified). Similarly, two function types that have the same return type but differ in that one specifies the parameter types and the other does not are compatible.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderfully detailed explanation, and for addressing all of my questions. Considering the changes in C 2023, it is probably best if I avoid passing parameters to functions without parameter declarations called via pointer.

Answer (score 6):

Under C17 and earlier, `functionPointer` is defined as a pointer to a function taking an *unspecified* number of arguments and returning `void`.  Such a function pointer is compatible with *any* function that returns `void`.

The [C11 standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) gives the following description for determining if two function types are compatible, section 6.7.6.3p15:

> **For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible
> return types.** Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are
> present, shall agree in the number of parameters and in use of the
> ellipsis terminator; corresponding parameters shall have compatible
> types. **If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is
> specified by a function declarator that is not part of a function
> definition and that contains an empty identifier list, the parameter
> list shall not have an ellipsis terminator and the type of each
> parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the
> application of the default argument promotions.** If one type has a
> parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function
> definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list, both
> shall agree in the number of parameters, and the type of each
> prototype parameter shall be compatible with the type that results
> from the application of the default argument promotions to the type of
> the corresponding identifier. (In the determination of type
> compatibility and of a composite type, each parameter declared with
> function or array type is taken as having the adjusted type and each
> parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the
> unqualified version of its declared type.)

The sections in bold are what applies here.  So assigning either `functionA` or `functionB` to `functionPointer` is well defined.

The problem however is how `functionA` is called through this pointer:

```
functionPointer = functionA;
functionPointer(&number);
```

Section 6.5.2.2p2 states the following constraint regarding function calls:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
> includes a prototype, the number of arguments shall agree with the
> number of parameters. Each argument shall have a type such that its
> value may be assigned to an object with the unqualified version of the
> type of its corresponding parameter.

Since the above is calling `functionA` with the wrong number of parameters, this is a constraint violation and the code therefore has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Starting with C23, the type of `functionPointer` is a pointer to a function that takes *no* parameters and returns `void`.  This is specified in section 6.7.6.3p13 of the [C23 standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3047.pdf)

> For a function declarator without a parameter type list: the effect is
> as if it were declared with a parameter type list consisting of the
> keyword `void`. A function declarator provides a prototype for the
> function

So `functionPointer = functionA` will likely generate a warning for an incompatible pointer conversion, and `functionPointer(&number)` will generate an error for calling a function with the wrong number of parameters.